# Compress data to chunks using Zlib

Tags: c, zlib

I want to compress a file with size > 50mb with zlib.
But I want the compressed file to be in chunks (for example, 32Kb chunks).

I don't want to read 32Kb of uncompressed file and compress it.
The compressed file should contain 32kb compressed chunks.
Compression should be reset after `avail_out = 32kb`.

I need to do it only with zlib and this is for random access.

This is what I have so far:

```
do {
    strm.avail_in = fread(in, 1, CHUNK, source);

    flush = feof(source) ? Z_FINISH : Z_FULL_FLUSH;
    strm.next_in = in;
    strm.next_out = out;

    strm.avail_out = CHUNK;
    deflate(&strm, flush);

    if (strm.avail_out == 0)
        have = tmp;
    else
        have = CHUNK - strm.avail_out;

    fwrite(out, 1, have, dest);

    tmp = strm.avail_out;

    if (tmp == 0)
        deflateReset(&strm);

} while (flush != Z_FINISH);
```

but there are several problems in this code.

1. When I reset the compression every 32Kb, I lose some compressed bytes that haven't been written yet because `avail_out` is full; and if I try to write them then the compressed chunk wouldn't be 32Kb anymore.
2. If I knew how much data has been compressed when `avail_out` is filled, I could reset the file position and begin compression from there.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you add some code of your current solution? I'm asking because this looks like a uni assignment, where you want someone else to do the work for you.

Comment: This is not a uni assignment.I edited the post.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to assure that you can exactly fill the desired size, but you can get very close.  See [`fitblk.c`](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/fitblk.c) for how to do it.

Comment: Thanks to the author of zlib.Although this is not the answer but I think this is as close as I can get.So I mark this as answer.